# Associate computer with Apple TV after fresh install

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, itunes, appletv

I just fresh installed my Mac with Snow Leopard - I copied back the iTunes library but my Apple TV now see's it as a new machine.

The problem now is that I've long since removed the physical files for TV shows I recorded, but they remain in my Apple TV because they're still 'in the library'. If I disconnect the Apple TV and reconnect it to the new computer profile, all that will be lost and I can't sync it back.

Is there anyway to make my fresh install appear to be the old install my Apple TV was connected to? I have complete backups of my entire disk prior to reinstalling 10.6 so if a file is needed then I hopefully already have it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK iTunes will have to re-establish a new connection to your AppleTV. What I suggest you to do is to "tweak" your Apple TV so you can SSH in and transfer your files out, then re-connnect and resync.

To "tweak" your Apple TV for SSH access, you will need something called a "[Patchstick](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=791)"

Once the steps in the link above are done, your AppleTV is ready for SSH access. SSH into your AppleTV, and copy all your video files out.

Next, invest in more storage, and never leave single copies of precious data in a single location any more.

Comment: I really can't be bothered to fiddle with the Apple TV like that! In fact, the problem isn't as bad as it sounds, I have a drobo with loads of the original EyeTV source's on it for these programs it's just a PITA to re-encode them all for Apple TV! But this is what I must do I guess, just wondered if there was an easy way to make it appear associated.

Comment: If you have your entire old hard disk backed up, you could try copying all of your \Users\*username*\Library files over, and also your iTunes folder.

It *just* might work.

Comment: I also have copies of everything I've bought on iTunes, it's just these recorded-off-tv shows that are going to probably take a week to re-encode all of.

Comment: If you do encoding on a regular basis, you might want to invest in the Elgato h.264 Turbo, it will speed up your encoding by a fair bit. http://www.elgato.com/elgato/int/mainmenu/products/Accessories/Turbo264HD/product1.en.html

Comment: Alright then, mate. See ya around.